# MapView add an action to custom annotation (the right arrow)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I create the annotation pins via this for loop:

```
UIButton *eventMore = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

for (i = 0; i < [results count]; i++) {
    //NSLog(@"Result: %i = %@", i, results[i]);
    //NSLog(@"%@",[[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"long"]);

    myAnn = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] init];
    location.latitude = (double)[[[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
    location.longitude = (double)[[[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"long"] doubleValue];
    myAnn.coordinate = location;
    myAnn.title = [[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];
    myAnn.subtitle = [[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"strap"];
    [eventMore addTarget:myAnn action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [locations addObject:myAnn];

    //NSLog(@"%i", [[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lat"]);
}
```

What I am trying to do with this is add the detail disclosure button to the right of the title/description on the annotation however this does not add one in, and all the tuts I have found for this do it using this method - but it isnt working, any advice?

And the code for the action:

```
-(void)btnClicked:(id)sender{
    UIAlertView *btnAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"msg" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [btnAlert show];
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't evenMore button be created inside your for loop? I wonder if doing it your way would cause the button to fire off the selector more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting the **CalloutAccessoryView** for your annotation.

***Sample code***

```
    for (i = 0; i < [results count]; i++) {

    MKPointAnnotation  *myAnn = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    location.latitude = (double)[[[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
    location.longitude = (double)[[[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"long"] doubleValue];
    myAnn.coordinate = location;
    myAnn.title = [[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];
    myAnn.subtitle = [[results objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"strap"];
    [locations addObject:myAnn];

   }


   - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

   static NSString *s = @"ann";
   MKAnnotationView *pin = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:s];
   if (!pin) {
    pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:s];
    pin.canShowCallout = YES;
    pin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"];

    pin.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(viewDetails) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button;

}
return pin;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for commenting, this is giving me the error: Property'rightCalloutAccessoryView' not found on the object of type 'CustomAnimation *'. Not sure what this means

Comment: your custom annotation may not have that property. I have provided a sample try that one

Comment: derive CustomAnnotion from MKAnnotationView

Comment: Thanks for this. I am almost there, the thing is, the method I am running the code in is: `-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` which doesnt have annotation in, can I add the annotation to the end of that?

Comment: Annotation and annotation view are different. My sample is the MKMapViewDelegate  method which provide annotation view for your annotation. You should add the button to the view. So implement that method as it is

Comment: @Anil Thanks for the feedback, I need the code inside the for loop within connectionDidFinishLoading but when i do `myAnn = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"ann"];` it says that annotation is undecalred (which it is) so where can I declare it within connectionDidFinishLoading?

Comment: I have edited my code.. The first part you can do it in  connectionDidFinishLoading. Second implement as it is

Comment: @Anil thanks for that! I have implemented this as you show, the pins still show but no buttons

Comment: @Anil, As you correctly say "Annotation and annotation view are different...", the first sample code line (myAnn.right...) in your answer is confusing since it implies that myAnn is both the id<MKAnnotation> and the MKAnnotationView (not recommended).  I suggest removing that.

Comment: have you checked the delegate method is getting called? What happens when you click on the pin?

Comment: @Anil the title and descriptions come up as normal

Comment: @AnnaKarenina Sure.. Thanks.. That i was initially answered i thought that myAnn is an annotation view.

Comment: No detail disclosure?? are you using MKPointAnnotation?

Comment: @Anil Yeah im using `MKPointAnnotation *myAnn = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];`

Comment: viewForAnnotation: is getting called? The code i provided is from my project its working perfectly for me

Comment: @Anil I have put an NSLog after the `viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{` and it isnt logging in the console so, maybe not then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30570/discussion-between-anil-and-josh-boothe)